# Trying to save text and output it on different screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've put together a text field that can take text and save it and output it into a label on the same controller page. My question is how do I use another controller page (using tab view controller) and output the same text on the second controller.

I've linked the label as the same IBOulet that the text is saved as.

Below is my code for the firstcontroller.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel* label;
@end

@implementation FirstViewController
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    self.label.text = @"";
    return TRUE;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    self.label.text = textField.text;
    return YES;
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    textField.text = @"";
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the information you want is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743107/passing-data-from-view-controller-to-tab-bar-controller-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UITabBarDelegate to listen when the user click on another tab to pass the text.

Please check this link [Class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarDelegate)

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

Or you can check this too [Class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarControllerDelegate)

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

With this you could get the new view controller to assign the value in a good way.

Let me know if it helps you

Comment: I'll try this out and let you know. Thanks, I really appreciate the response.

Comment: No I wasn't certain how to go about using your answer unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Really, a `UITextField` is not a place to store data for any significant amount of time, as Model information should not be stored in a `UIView`. If you'd like this text to be accessible from multiple `UIViewController`s, you should create a Model object that can store the string, and persist regardless of what happens with your view controllers.

You can pass this text to the model object by having your `UIViewController` be a delegate for the `UITextField`. The `UIViewController` should then be made to conform to `<UITextFieldDelegate>` so that you can listen for :

`- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`

When this is called, pass the text to your model. The model could be set up with a Singleton pattern, just have 1 static model object accessible globally. When your app exits, you could write this object to disk using `<NSCoding>`, so that you can read it back in again next time the app starts.

For non-trivial data, I'd recommend using CoreData.

tl;dr- dont pass text to other controllers directly from the textfield.