# How to transfer a variable between two classes

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have the first class:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
    _camera_button.hidden = true;
    _camera_imageview.hidden = false;
    [_next_camera setEnabled:YES];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage);
    [self upload_selfie:imageData];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

And I am wanting to transfer the variable: `imageData` to this class:

```
- (IBAction)upload_selfie:(NSData *)sender{
    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:imageData];

    // Save PFFile
    [imageFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // Hide old HUD, show completed HUD (see example for code)

            // Create a PFObject around a PFFile and associate it with the current user
            PFObject *userPhoto = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"UserPhoto"];
            [userPhoto setObject:imageFile forKey:@"imageFile"];

            // Set the access control list to current user for security purposes
            userPhoto.ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];

            PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
            [userPhoto setObject:user forKey:@"user"];

            [userPhoto saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
//                    _loader6.hidden = true;
//                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toquestion" sender:self];
                }
                else{
                    // Log details of the failure
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }];
        }
    }];

}
```

Where I have tried:

```
PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:imageData];
```

But I receive the error "Use of undeclared identifier"?ces where I refrence `imageData` should I somewhere else?

Also these are the only two pla

Please may you explain why and what I can do about this?

Comment: please see my answer to this question
[here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036921/trying-to-save-text-and-output-it-on-different-screen/23073942#23073942

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive this error because your variable name is **sender**:

```
- (IBAction)upload_selfie:(NSData *)sender
```

You need change your code to:

```
PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:sender];
```

PS. It seems that you use **upload_selfie:** method for two aims: a) interface builder action handler; b) method for saving photo. It is better to make two separate methods.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the parameter as `sender` so that's the name you should use: `PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:sender];`.

Though, to be more understandable, choosing a different name would be good.